# Bash: How do I make a command line call a script and pass two strings?

Tags: bash, shell, input

I have a simple bash script named `text.sh` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read username
read password
echo "script attempted with $username $password"
```

I want to call it using something like this:

```
[root@ip-192.168.0.0 root]# ./test.sh bing s3cr3t
```

And have it echo back:

```
script attempted with bing s3cr3t
```

I can use `<<<` to get `bing` to print, but not both.  I'm sure this is simple, but my Google-fu is failing since I don't know what keywords to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to access the command-line arguments, not to read from standard input. A script with the proper method:

```
#!/bin/bash
username="$1"
password="$2"
echo "script attempted with $username $password"
```

The special variables `$1`, `$2` &c. contain the first, second &c. arguments passed on the running command line. More information available [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html), among many other places.

Comment: I remembered it was something simple, but couldn't remember this, thank you!  I'll accept in 10 min, when it allows me to.